# Is there an easier way to get everyone to include tags when the save their MS Word Document?

Tags: ms-word, metadata, meta-tags, power-automate

I have users that save their notes on a Word Document from a template we provided. We wanted them to add [meta-data tags upon save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bolyF.png), but they never remember to.

I was thinking to edit the template to include a table so that the users can remember to enter it. Would there be a way for the Word Document to auto-populate the tags if I included a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zo4H.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

From Insert > Text > Quick Parts > Document Property

Upon save, it'll populate. So Tags would be under "Keywords"